# Is there a way to log wifi probe request?

Tags: wi-fi, logging

I am able to log wifi probe request with script like [hoover](https://github.com/xme/hoover), [probeSniffer](https://github.com/xdavidhu/probeSniffer), and my favorite for the moment [probemon](https://github.com/nikharris0/probemon) on my ubuntu machine with a card able to run in monitor mode.

Is it possible to do the same on android ? a rooted android is not a problem.

But I guess one major problem would be to be able to switch the wifi card in monitor mode, if it is possible at all, depending on the driver.

Is there even script or software or app to be able to log the wifi probe request ?

At the very least, one can try to use the script I mention above but there are not meant to be run on android.

My question is perhaps too general. I use a moto G 4G (XT1039) with LineageOS 14.1 (peregrine)

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, buy a raspberry pi zero (W ?) with a usb wifi key that does monitor mode. This will be almost as portable than a phone but not as much.

You need the battery too to power the rpi0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use you're favorite sniffing tools with kali NetHunter os  on a rooted device or with the kali NetHunter app if the device has support for monitor mode